# google photos backup app

Tags: macos, photos, google

Will Google Photos Backup avoid creating duplicates if I use the app to upload from two separate computers with overlapping photo collections in Mac Os Photos?﻿

Comment: Why don't you try with a small sample library?

Answer (score 1):

Google photos does a really good job of deduping!  I have loaded from multiple pc's, iPads & iPhone & not seen any duplicates!   I'm loving it!